# Matplotlib: move graph to the right

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

I have two graphs with in one image, each with 5 points. Their value on the X axis is not important, all that I require is that they're all equally distributed on it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [43,51,44,73,60]
data2 = [34,25,42,53,61]

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(data, '-o', color='#000000', lw=1, ms=6)
ax.plot(data2, '-o', color='#000000', lw=1, ms=6)

plt.show()
```

This creates a graph like the one below.
[image]

I need the second graph (the one using the data2 points) to start from 5 on the X axis, not from 0, meaning it'll have the points at (5,34),(6,25),(7,42),(8,53),(9,61). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of the X values,

```
x = [5,6,7,8,9]
```

and use

```
ax.plot(x, data2, ...)
```

Note that you could also use [`range(5,10)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) or numpy's [`arange(5,10)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange) or [`linspace(5,9,5)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) to generate the X values.